# How do I break a loop inside of a loop in python?

Tags: python

This code is a loop which reviews vocabulary words. For some reason, my break isn't working.

Here are my words that this program uses:

```
Vocab ={'Adherent' : "a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower.",
'Incoherent' : "without logical or meaningful connection; disjointed; rambling",
'Inherent' : "existing in someone or something as a permanent and inseparable element, quality, or attribute" ,
'DiffuseADJ' : "characterized by great length or discursiveness in speech or writing; wordy"}
```

Here is my loop:

```
while 1:
    ques1= raw_input("Would you like a list of the vocabulary words, or would you like to play a game? Type 'words' or 'game': ")
    if ques1 == 'words':  
        ques11= raw_input("Type 'w' for words only, type 'wd' for words and definitions, type 'd' for definitions only: ")
        if ques11 == "w":
            for key,value in Vocab.iteritems():
                print key
        elif ques11 == "wd":
            for key,value in Vocab.iteritems():
                print key,"-", value
        elif ques11 == "d":
            for key,value in Vocab.iteritems():
                print value
    elif ques1 == 'game':
        game=raw_input("Type 'rw' for random words: ")
        if game == 'rw':
            while 1:
                y = random.choice(Vocab.keys())
                print y
                t2=raw_input("What is the definition?: ")
                if t2 in Vocab[y]:
                    print 'All those words were in the definition!'
                    print Vocab[y]
                elif t2 not in Vocab[y]:
                    print Vocab[y]
                elif t2 == 'menu': break
                raw_input("Hit 'enter': ") 








    else:
        raw_input("Hit 'enter': ")
```

For some reason the break for the game loop doesn't return to the 'ques1'. Why won't this break work?

Comment: Coz your code is wrapped in `while 1`. even though it `breaks` on inside loop it will still continue on outer while

Comment: @Pilot I want it to return to the original question, but it wont

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the `break` statement will never be reached if `t2` is not in `Vocab`. You can change

```
elif t2 == 'menu': break
```

to

```
if t2 == 'menu': break
```